# Matplotlib: eps-plots lost quality

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following plots, that I produce with `matplotlib` in two different formats: `png` and `eps`
[image]
**(Left: EPS.  Right: PNG)**

In the plot I use commands like `annotate (with alpha=0.3), fill (with alpha=0.3), plot and savefig("s.eps")`

Can someone explain this drastic loss of quality in the eps-file? 
(this file is needed for latex)

Here again is the eps-file (zoomed in): 
[image]

Comment: To be clear: the left one is the eps and the _loss of quality_ is missing alpha, right?

Comment: I edited my question. Yes left is the eps, and loss of quality is the missing alpha AND the lines are somehow "no natural"

Comment: if you found a solution please post it as an answer instead of editing your question to add a link.

Comment: also, eps does not support alpha (that link gets around it by putting a bitmap in an eps, it's not a vector graphic any more) and I suspect the issue with your lines in viewer based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [here](http://osxastrotricks.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/rasterized-graphics-with-matplotlib-to-preserve-plot-transparencies-for-apj-figures/):

It is based on rasterizing the image first and than saving it as eps-figure.

```
ax.set_rasterization_zorder(1)
```

The other alternative was to save the plot as pdf and than convert it  to eps. (`pdftoeps -eps`). But I found the first solution produced better results.